# How can I check the src attribute of every script tag in an html document

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I want to check every `<script>` tag in an HTML document using **Cypress** to make sure the src attribute matches the string '^js'.

```js
<script src="js/somejsfile.js">
```

matches

```js
<script src="somejsfile.js">
```

does not match.

I've tried

```js
 cy.document()
        .get('head script')
        .each(($match) => {
            cy.wrap($match)
            .invoke('attr', 'src')
            .then((src) => {
                expect(src).to.match(/^js/)
            })
        })
```

but src is always undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some mods going on during page visit (as you noted elsewhere), so the trick is to `cy.request()` the page.

Unfortunately with `cy.request()` the page isn't attached to the DOM that Cypress wants to run commands against, so you can't query with Cypress commands but native queries still work (and are sufficient because there's nothing async going on).

```js
cy.request(my-url)
  .its('body')          // NB the response body, not the body of your page
  .then(content => {

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/html')

    const scripts = doc.querySelectorAll('head script')    // native query
    const srcs = [...scripts].map(script => script.getAttribute('src'))

    expect(srcs.every(src => src.endsWith('js'))).to.eq(true)
    srcs.forEach(src => expect(src).to.match(/^js/))
  })
```

Comment: The question asked for a check that the src starts with js/. How is a solution that is testing for `endswith('js')` working? Where's the startswith?

Comment: You can apply the assertion given in the question, but it's not the point of the question.