# Cypress: How to get elements from a variable with HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, api, cypress

I'm currently working on API testing. The API that I'm testing is returning an HTML body. How do I get an element from the response body? If I visit the link, it returns an iframe and I cannot access it properly inside cy.origin.

How to get the `https://test-develop.test.net/download/cd668080-be63-11ed-8328-41d4c5da193d` or the `XudSov7Y6JDm` ? I've been going through this for hours but can't seem to find a solution :/

```
var message = `<html>

<body style="background-color:#f5f5f5;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;padding:24px 0;">
    <div style="margin:0 auto 24px auto;text-align:center">

        <img width="130" src="cid:quipper_logo" alt="School LINK" />

  </div>
        <hr style="border:none;" />
        <div style="margin:12px auto;max-width:540px;background-color:white;border:1px #dcdcdc solid;padding:20px;">
            <p><strong>** This email is automatically generated. Please do not reply. **</strong></p>


            <p>Your Excel spreadsheet for is ready to download.</p>



            <p>Please note: you will need to enter the supplied username and password to download the file.</p>




            <p><strong>Download:</strong> <a
                    href="https://test-develop.test.net/download/cd668080-be63-11ed-8328-41d4c5da193d">https://test-develop.test.net/download/cd668080-be63-11ed-8328-41d4c5da193d</a>
            </p>


            <p>Username: test@test.com</p>
            <p>Password: XudSov7Y6JDm</p>



        </div>
</body>

</html>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `regex` in python:

```
import re

message = # insert you HTML Body 
link = re.search(r'https://\S+', message).group(0)
password = re.search(r'Password: (\S+)', message).group(1)
print(download_link)
print(password)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please see this answer [How can I check the src attribute of every script tag in an html document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71890065/16997707) that uses [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to extract elements from the HTML string.

In your case there's one `<a>`, so slightly different

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(message, 'text/html')
const href = doc.querySelector('a').href
```

This is broadly the way to do it, but I'm a bit worried about the reference to `cy.origin()` as there are some things that don't work inside that command.

In any case give it a spin, if not working update details of that origin call.